# How to detect a file rename using Rugged?

Tags: rugged

I'm a novice Rugged user, and I'm attempting to detect file renames in the commit history. I'm diffing each commit against its first parent, as follows:

```
repo = Rugged::Repository.discover("foo")
walker = Rugged::Walker.new(repo)
walker.sorting(Rugged::SORT_TOPO)
walker.push("master")

walker.each.take(200).each do |commit|
  puts commit.oid  
  puts commit.message

  diffs = nil

  # Handle Root commit
  if commit.parents.count > 0 then
    diffs = commit.parents[0].diff(commit)
  else
    diffs = commit.diff(nil)
  end

  (files,additions,deletions) = diffs.stat
  puts "Files changed: #{files}, Additions: #{additions}, Deletions: #{deletions}"  

  paths = [];
  diffs.each_delta do |delta|
    old_file_path = delta.old_file[:path]
    new_file_path = delta.new_file[:path]   

    puts delta.status
    puts delta.renamed?
    puts delta.similarity
    paths += [delta]
 end

 puts "Paths:"
 puts paths
 puts "===================================="

end
walker.reset
```

However, when I do have a rename, the program will output an addition and a removal (A and D status). This matches the output of `git log --name-status`.

On the other hand, I found out that using `git log --name-status --format='%H' --follow -- b.txt` correctly shows the rename as `R100`.

The repo history and the outputs of git can be seen in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/ifigueroap/60716bbf4aa2f205b9c9

My question is how to use the Diff, or Delta objects of Rugged to detect such a file rename...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Before accessing `diffs.stat`, you should call `diffs.find_similar!` with `:renames => true`. That'll modify the `diffs` object to do include rename information. This is not done by default, as the underlying operation is quite complex and not needed in most cases.

Check the documentation for `find_similar!` here: https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/blob/e96d26174b2bf763e9dd5dd2370e79f5e29077c9/ext/rugged/rugged_diff.c#L310-L366 for more options.